# database project takes a long time to open

Tags: visual-studio-2008, database-project

Whenever I open my SLN that has multiple database projects under it, it takes a very long time (10 to 15 mintues) to open. The messages I get are:

```
Analyzing database schema. Your database projects will be ready after 23000 operations are completed.
Analyzing database schema. Your database projects will be ready after 45000 operations are completed.
Analyzing database schema. Your database projects will be ready after 59871 operations are completed.
Analyzing database schema. Your database projects will be ready after 63254 operations are completed.
Analyzing database schema. Your database projects will be ready after 87698 operations are completed.
```

Visual Studio does not give me an indication of what it is analyzing?

Is there any way for me to speed up this process?

Answer (score 6):

It's serializing a DBMDL file.  This takes quite a long time depending on the size/complexity of your project.  One of ours is 150MB, for example and it takes almost 20 minutes to complete all of the "operations."

I would recommend having one project per solution - it **continually** updates these DBMDL files in your Temp folder until they are finished, then copies them to your working folder and can cause quite a bit of disk activity.

I'm also going to see about optimizing these - the amount of time it takes is really a roadblock in some cases.