# SSDT Project Stuck on "Analyzing database schema."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I recently added about 500 stored procs to my solution (code generated) and I'm now getting "Analyzing database schema. Your database projects will be ready after XXXXX operations are completed". It takes an hour or so to resolve these which is a work stoppage for me. When I close and reload visual studio the process has to start all over again.

I found a few posts on stack overflow talking about how to fix this, but none of the [recommended fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734019/analyzing-database-schema-takes-hours) have helped. Most references to this issue are related to a bug that was fixed about 2 years ago. Here are some of the things I've tried:

1. Removing obj/sql directories along with dbmdl file
2. Upgrading to the latest version of SSDT
3. Turning off auto-update statistics on the sql project.

I don't think I have an unreasonable number objects in my database project, but here is what I have (based on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2007/09/24/script-of-the-day-count-all-objects-in-a-database.aspx) script):

```
77 CHECK constraints
774 Default or DEFAULT constraints
477 FOREIGN KEY constraints
72 Inlined table-functions
380 PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints
1360 Stored procedures
67 System tables
240 User tables
```

Please help!

Comment: The bad thing with SSDT is that this situation happens and as far as I know there is no way to fix it right now. You need just wait sometimes and that's it... The only thing you did not mentioned in your post is that you need to upgrade DACFx framework also. It can help, but anyway you'll have this situation from time to time